# Object Disposed Exception in Delete Button

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create a delete button that will delete the information of a selected user in a database. Whenever a user clicks on one of the rows it fills the textboxes with the corresponding data. The user can then select the delete button and delete the selected data from the table. However, the error, System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.', keeps coming up and I'm not sure why.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Information info = new Information
        {
            username = usernametxt.Text,
            password = passwordtxt.Text,
            status = statustxt.Text
        };
        db.Informations.DeleteOnSubmit(info);
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Note, the try-catch exception is never used as the program crashes before it is ever thrown with the previously mentioned error.

Comment: Do you have something like `db.Dispose();` somewhere? Or `using (db) { /*code*/ }`?

Comment: Yep, and right there you dispose of `db` the moment it leaves the scope of the `using` block.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar How does it leave the scope of the using block?

Comment: The code within the using block finishes executing, the execution moves onto the next line (`}`). Essentially: by the time the method completes, `db` has been disposed of.

Comment: To be clear: the whole point of the using block is to dispose of the thing it uses once the using block is complete.

Comment: So now you know what to do: find our where/when `db` is disposed. We can't do that for you.